# Instead of pre-fill field, I get Undefined method `name' for ["Yes", true]:Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, simple-form

When I want to edit my form or when there are validation errors, I am not able to pre-fill an association field.

- If I add a label_method for name, I get the error message `` undefined method `name' for ["Yes", true]:Array ``
- Alternatively, when I delete the label_method, the form field only says *'Yes'* instead of the name of the field (name of 'room').

new.js.erb

```
$("#dynamic-rooms").empty();
<% @rooms.each do |acc| %>
    $("#dynamic-rooms").append('<option value="<%= acc.id %>"><%= acc.name %></option>')
<% end %>
```

form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for [@hotel, @reservation] do |f|%>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :rooms do |room| %>
    <%= room.input :room_type, collection: @room_type_list, prompt: "Select type of room", label:false,
        input_html:{
        id: "room_type"
      }%>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.association :room, collection: @rooms,  input_html:{
      value: @rooms.object_id,
      id: "dynamic-rooms"
    } %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    var room_type = $("#room_type").val();

    $.ajax({
      url: "/hotels/<%= @hotel.id %>/reservations/new",
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {room_type: room_type},
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.error('AJAX Error: ' + status + error);
      },
      success: function (response) {
    }
  });
  });

   $(document).on("change", "#room_type", function(){
    var room_type = $("#room_type").val();

    $.ajax({
      url: "/hotels/<%= @hotel.id %>/reservations/new",
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {room_type: room_type},
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.error('AJAX Error: ' + status + error);
      },
      success: function (response) {
    }
  });
  });
</script>
```

controller

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
  # skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
  def new
    @user = current_user
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
    @reservation = Reservation.new
    @room_type_list = @hotel.room_types
    @rooms = []
    if params[:room_type].present?
      @rooms = RoomType.find(params[:room_type]).rooms
    end
    if request.xhr?
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json {
        render json: {rooms: @rooms}
      }
        format.js
      end
    end

    authorize @reservation
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
    @reservation = Reservation.new(reservation_params)
    @reservation.hotel = @hotel
    authorize @reservation
    if @reservation.save
      redirect_to hotel_path(@hotel)
    else

      # @room_type = @reservation.room.room_type
      @room_type_list = @hotel.room_types
      # @room = @reservation.room
      render 'new'


    end
  end

  private
    def reservation_params
      params.require(:reservation).permit(:room_id, :arrival, :departure, :payment, :reservation_contact_id, option_ids:[],
      reservation_contact_attributes: [:id, :first_name,
      :last_name, :zipcode, :city, :street, :street_number],
        rooms_attributes: [:id,:name, :room_type_id,
          room_types_attributes: [:id, :name]])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means this code

```
<%= acc.name %>
```

acc is **Array** which contain ["Yes",true] instead of **Room** object.

You have a instance method **.rooms** in **RoomType** class. Double check that method that it is returning the correct **Room** objects.

Comment: thank you for the response. The problem indeed lies at @rooms, but only if it's not rendered via the ```if params[:room_type].present?
      @rooms = RoomType.find(params[:room_type]).rooms
    end```. The room_type is set to empty and consequently so is the room field, but I don't have a clue how to solve this.